# using php and html to make a user grocery list

Tags: php, html, forms

I can't seem to find a decent way to go about this part of the project. The user has in front of them a table that was drawn from a sql query using a for loop. Now, the user will want to click on items that they see. If they click the price, it edits the price. if they click the product name or description, it add it to their shopping list. When I use checkboxes, it seems to me that the handler script needs to know what all the checkboxes are in advance. A cookie handler needs the same. I would hate to use javascript, but is it my only way?

Comment: javascript/ajax would make it convenient .. ondblclick and onclick on the tds ...

Comment: Please clarify: What happens exactly when the user clicks price or name. "It edits the price" is not significant enough to understand the problem you have. Is there an overall button to submit the request, and the form should pass the item to be updated or added to basket?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript wouldn't necessarily be your only way, but it will probably be a better and easier way. I have personal experience with [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) but there are tons of examples if you search for javascript editable grid.

With that being said, if you wanted to not use javascript, you could output your data as a form containing a table, with text boxes in each cell and allow the user to submit the changes back as a form post. I would think that using Javascript would be more palatable.